# Google Drive API - Invalid Credentials

Tags: oauth-2.0, google-drive-api

I want to use a scripted approach (probably via) curl, to access some simple info from the drive api, like creation date. Essentially I want to script what I can do in their web interface: https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/list.

I having been using a curl command that they expose in a query at the above link:

```
curl \
  'https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files?corpora=user&q=createdTime%20%3E%20%272021-11-23T12%3A00%3A00%27&key=[YOUR_API_KEY]' \
  --header 'Authorization: Bearer [YOUR_ACCESS_TOKEN]' \
  --header 'Accept: application/json' \
  --compressed
```

I have created an API key for this purpose (unrestricted for now). And used this app to generate an access token:  https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?scope=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.googleapis.com%2Fauth%2Fdrive&redirect_uri=urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob&response_type=code&client_id=735795831119-kcpkamhiaojavqrt67mti7thcaa6ce87.apps.googleusercontent.com

But I have spent hours chasing my tail over the 401 Invalid Credentials error. Any help on getting a more specific error message, or better way to do this seemingly simple query would be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The result of the link below is an **Authorization code**.

```
https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?scope=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.googleapis.com%2Fauth%2Fdrive&redirect_uri=urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob&response_type=code&client_id=735795831119-kcpkamhiaojavqrt67mti7thcaa6ce87.apps.googleusercontent.com
```

You need to exchange it to `https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token` to generate an **Access Token:**

```
curl \
--request POST \
--data "code=[Authentcation code from authorization link]&client_id=[Application Client Id]&client_secret=[Application Client Secret]&redirect_uri=urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob&grant_type=authorization_code" \
https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token
```

The result of the curl above is something like this:

```
{
  "access_token": "access token here",
  "expires_in": 3599,
  "refresh_token": "refresh token here",
  "scope": "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive",
  "token_type": "Bearer"
}
```

Now you have the access token, you can paste it in the code below alongside with your API key.

```
curl \
  'https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files?corpora=user&q=createdTime%20%3E%20%272021-11-23T12%3A00%3A00%27&key=[YOUR_API_KEY]' \
  --header 'Authorization: Bearer [YOUR_ACCESS_TOKEN]' \
  --header 'Accept: application/json' \
  --compressed
```

**Note:**

- Make sure you enable the Drive API in GCP
- **Application Client Id** and **Application Client Secret** can be found after you created an **OAuth 2.0 Client ID** in GCP.

### Reference:

- [DaImTo answer on How to connect to the Google Drive API using cURL](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51376871/14606052).

Comment: Yes I will. I have gotten yanked into other things for the moment, and sorry but never saw any notification of your answer, but certainly do appreciate it! And will be back! thx

Comment: Thanks! It does work now.